# php block start with <?php= instead of <?php

Tags: php

Hi All
I download a free chat script that in it's php files all of php code blocks start with `<?php=` instead of `<?php` or `<?` for print variables and constants that causes some problems and show error messages .
i want to know that how to solve this problem for php script work correctly

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: You can just do a find and replace <?php= with <?= if you think that's the problem.

Comment: in fact no error display just all of same php code display in pages and not work exactly . if want find and replace all of <?php= with <?php this is difficult

Comment: Since you are unable to explain the circumstances of the error, you should provide the download link for said free chat script.

Comment: this is link of free download chat script:[chantlive](http://www.chantlive.com/)

Comment: There is not a single instance of `<?php=` in that script. You should have looked closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your server's php config (php.ini file)
add

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: i try it . but Since this script for print a variable for example with "$chatname" name uses <?=$chatname?> show a parse error like: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\chant\core\reg.php on line 85`

Comment: I ask to All offer me a free php chat script with Ajax , create and  define chat rooms Capability

Answer (score 1):

At my understanding this `<?php=` is **wrong**..

Your currently problem is not the short open tags `<?`, but this code

```
<?=
```

means you are doing exactly this

```
<?php echo $someVar;
```

so all you have to do is change for the correct syntax.